# Error while including jsp with angular inside non angular jsp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

I included a jsp with angular directives (A.jsp) inside a non-angular jsp(B.jsp).

If I access A.jsp directly those models "{{X}} {{Y}}" are resolving correctly to

Xvalue Yvalue

But if I access A.jsp through B.jsp I am seeing unresolved ng-model s.

{{X}} {{Y}}

What could be the reason?

My code:

Inside B.jsp

```
<div id="Bcontent" style="display:block;">
                <jsp:include page="/jsp/superqueue/A.jsp"/>
</div>
```

A.jsp

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=webroot%>/js/angular.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=webroot%>/js/angular-sanitize.js">      </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/A.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="AApp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ACtrl.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="AApp">
<div ng-controller="ACtrl">
    <h1 class="a-title">{{X}} {{Y}}</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. A.jsp is showing up inside B.jsp but none of the ng-models are resolving to their values. If I access A.jsp directly they are resolving fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A.jsp

```
<div ng-app="AApp">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=webroot%>/js/angular.min.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=webroot%>/js/angular-sanitize.js">      </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/A.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="AApp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ACtrl.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="ACtrl">
    <h1 class="a-title">{{X}} {{Y}}</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

and add meta tags of A.jsp to B.jsp if not already there